# Meteor with Zurb Foundation For Apps

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, meteor, zurb-foundation-apps

Im fairly new to programming. I am using Meteor and AngularJS for a new web application. However, I want to be able to use the elements/css that 'Zurb Foundation For Apps' uses...

I know how to use Bootstrap by using this in the cmd:

```
$ meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```

But I cannot find, nor understand how I would use Zurb Foundation For Apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
meteor add matthew:foundation5-sass
```

https://atmospherejs.com/matthew/foundation5-sass

or

```
meteor add nsmeta:zurb-foundation
```

https://atmospherejs.com/nsmeta/zurb-foundation

You can find more meteor zurb related packages here.

https://atmospherejs.com/?q=zurb

It looks like Zurb has no official meteor package released but luckily other people have made their own packages(links above)...hopefully they keep them updated :)

Comment: Thanks, I will try. So this will enable me to use the html elements/templates from Foundation? aswell as enable me to use foundation's css/javascript?